# When programmatically adding conditional element to webform, I get errors

Tags: webforms, nodes

I'm trying to add a new conditional attribute to a bunch of webforms using a script.  There are already 12 conditions, and I need to add a 13th one.

My code looks like this in a basic script module which has $node available:

```
if(stuff_is_true){
 $new_component = array(
  'nid' => $node->nid,
  'rgid' => '13',
  'andor' => NULL,
  'action' => 'hide',
  'target_type' => 'component',
  'target' => '22',
  'weight' => '13',
  'rules' => array(
    '0' => array(
      'nid' => $node->nid,
      'rgid' => '13',
      'rid' => '0',
      'source_type' => 'component',
      'source' => '21',
      'operator' => 'equal',
      'value' => '0',
    ),
  ),
);

$node->webform['conditionals'][] = $new_component;

// Save the changes
node_save($node);
```

All of this works if put into a hook_node_view() (without doing a node_save obviously), so I know it's structured properly.

The problem comes during node_save($node) which throws an error like:

```
Duplicate entry '3033-0' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {webform_conditional}...
```

(3033 is the nid, and the 0 is the rgid key).

Basically, what it's doing (I think) is trying to re-submit the whole $node->webform['conditionals'] array as NEW data, so existing components hit this "duplicate primary key" error (because they already exist).

How can I tell node_save to only ADD my new conditional item to the end of the existing array instead of trying to re-insert the whole thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if there's really no clean way to do this.  What I realized is that it was easier to just remove all existing conditions, and then re-add them all with the additional condition included.  So I started by setting:

```
$node->webform['conditionals'] = array(); //remove all conditions
node_save($node); //save the node, removing all old conditions
$node->webform['conditionals'] = $new_array_of_conditions; //add entire new array of condtions
node_save($node); //save the node with new conditions
```

This doesn't break anything on old nodes because no data or anything else is reliant upon conditions...so removing them doesn't hurt anything or lose any crucial data.